# Инпуты с типом поля email не сериализуются

Tags: javascript, html5

На форме попробывать валидацию html5 и столкнулся с проблемой, есть поле email которое в javascript почемуто не сериализуется

```
<input name="email" type="email" required>
```

если записать как

```
<input name="email" type="text">
```

то сериализация формы работает: `$('#myform').serialize()`
Как сериализовать `input` c `type="email"` ?

*Update from comment:*

```
$("#js-button-send-order").click(function (e) { 
  $.ajax({ 
    url: "navigator_order_action.php", 
    data: $('#js-order-navigator').serialize(), 
    type: 'post', 
   success: function(response) { } 
  });
  return false; 
});
```

форма

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="frmBook" id="js-order-navigator">
<table border="0">

    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top"><span style="color: #ff0000">*</span><b>Имя</b></td>
        <td valign="top" align="left"><input name="name" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top"><span style="color: #ff0000">*</span><b>E-mail</b></td>
        <td valign="top" align="left"><input name="email" type="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top"><b></b></td>
        <td valign="top" align="left"><input id="js-button-send-order" name="btnSubmit"
                                             value="Отправить" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Update with code snippet*

```js
$("#js-button-send-order").click(function(e) {
  var fData = $('#js-order-navigator').serialize();
  console.log(fData);
  console.log($('#js-order-navigator').find("[name='email']").length);
  $.ajax({
    url: "navigator_order_action.php",
    data: fData,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) {}
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" name="frmBook" id="js-order-navigator">
  <table border="0">

    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top"><span style="color: #ff0000">*</span><b>Имя</b></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left"><input name="name" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top"><span style="color: #ff0000">*</span><b>E-mail</b></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left"><input name="email" type="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top"><b></b></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left"><input id="js-button-send-order" name="btnSubmit" value="Отправить" type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Neodrive, пожалуйста, добавьте пример код с воспроизводимой проблемой

Comment: Я завернул js и html во "Фрагмент кода ...", и изменил `type="text"` на `type="email"`. Форма сериализуется.

Comment: Как Вы пришли к выводу, что "поле email ... не сериализуется", и что значит "которое в javascript"?

Comment: @Igor , но, похоже, данные из неё таки не отправляются (в *FormData* отладчика хрома пусто)

Comment: @br3t пoгодите, речь же идет о результате `$().serialize()`?

Comment: @Igor,  сам `serialize` произошёл, а вот данные не отправились. Поправьте меня, если это не так.

Comment: я добавил скриншот как выглядит результат serialize формы, значение для поля email отсутствует...

Comment: @Neodrive , есть ли ещё на странице какие-то скрипты, могущие вмешиваться в работу вашего неработающего кода?

Comment: даже если в консоле запустить $('#js-order-navigator').serialize() то в строке которая получается после сериализации нет email, не уверен что на консоль хрома могут влиять какие то скрипты

Comment: @Neodrive Все, я догадался. Сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 0):

```
<режим телепатии>
```

У Вас на странице есть другая форма/элемент (формы/элементы) с `id="js-order-navigator"`, которая идет раньше показанной в вопросе, и в которой нет инпута с `name="email"`. Селектор `$('#js-order-navigator')` находит именно эту форму, а не ту, про которую Вы думаете.

Вы можете заменить селектор на `$(this).closest("form").serialize()`, хотя если у Вас и элементов с `id="js-button-send-order"` больше одного - работать все равно не будет.

Не дублируйте значения атрибутов `id` - они предназначены для уникальной (в смысле единственности) идентификации DOM-элементов на странице. Используйте классы, помня в то же время о том, что селектор по классу будут возвращать jQuery-обертку вокруг нескольких DOM-элементов.

```
</режим телепатии>
```